# Difference between Hashcash proof of work algorithm and Ethash proof of work algorithm?

Tags: proof-of-work

Understand that each proof of work algorithm has its pros and cons.

Difference between Hashcash proof of work algorithm and Ethash proof of work algorithm?

Nathan Aw

Answer (score 1):

Hashcash and Ethash are two different things and not directly comparable. Hashcash is the idea of using hashes for a proof of work system. it can be used with any hash function.

Ethash is a specific hash function. It is used in a hashcash proof of work system, specifically the one used in Ethereum.

Hashcash is not comparable to Ethash because it is not a hash function at all.

Answer (score 0):

One major difference between them is that Ethash(Modified Dagger-Hashimoto Algorithm) is ASIC resistant due to its memory hardness (Algorithm works on precompiled dataset of size > 1GB) , whereas Hashcash algorithm is not ASIC resistant as it uses SHA-256 hash function which do not require any memory to work with.